# install in /usr/local/ using apt-get

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Is there way to specifically install in path /usr/local using apt-get ? I am using Linux Mint 16 and I want to install some libraries in this path. All of my installed libraries are installed in /usr/ and only some of them are available in /usr/local

I was able to install boost library by means of tar.gz file but is there a way to do it using apt-get install ?

Comment: Besides belonging on SU, this also is a duplicate of [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory).

Comment: That's why I was not getting its answer here. Sorry for the trouble?

Comment: No trouble. StackExchange works like this. Also don't worry about your question being closed as a duplicate (if it is closed). It's all for the better and allows for people to find what they need quicker.

Comment: @user166289 What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why do you believe `/usr/local` is superior to `/usr`?

Answer (score 4):

There should not be any way to do that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168754/841108)

This is because the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) explicitly reserves `/usr/local/` for program and data used system-wide, but installed locally by the sysadmin. Please take time to read that FHS (which also provide rationale).

BT, you often cannot move a binary file and related data, because most programs contain builtin file paths. In practice, to install them under `/usr/local/`  you'll generally need to re-configure and re-compile them.

So a `.deb` package installing file under `/usr/local/` would be against the conventions and standards.

Comment: I don't get it. Am I not the sysadmin of my own machine?

Comment: Then, compile the software from source code.

Comment: I don't dispute the end result, but in light of your answer, should that mean that the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard makes a difference between "installed by apt-get" and "installed by make install"?

Comment: Yes. Most GNU software install by default with the `/usr/local/`  prefix (if you don't give any to `configure`). But the distribution is packaging then with `/usr/` prefix (i.e. is `configure`-ing them with `--prefix=/usr/` ...)

Comment: So it doesn't count as being the sysadmin if it's installed by *sudo* apt-get? Seems easier to me to rationalize that someone kinda messed up and it stayed that way for historical reasons.

Comment: No, it is perfectly logical: with `apt-get`  all stuff is installed under `/usr/`  (and you'll use `apt-get remove` to remove a package). For programs you have compiled, it goes into `/usr/local/` and you need to uninstall it properly. The FHS (which you should read) gives a good rationale.

Comment: @zneak It's not distinguishing who installs the software, but who *compiles* it. This is a more useful distinction, partly because package maintainers have to jump through a lot of hoops to make sure their software installs and works gracefully on *every* system. If you install non-packaged software to the same location, you could potentially have conflicts with system packages, which should otherwise just work, and you lose the freedom to compile software however you want to (as you have with `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 2):

No, and you shouldn't need to.

The purpose of `/usr/local` is to distinguish software which was compiled & installed by the *local* administrator from software distributed with the system (that is, software which can be installed via `apt-get`).

By installing non-packaged software to `/usr`, you risk causing conflicts, which could even cause system packages to fail for no apparent reason (e.g. if you overwrite a library with a newer version, or an incompatible build).

Package maintainers have to do a lot of extra work when compiling a package, to ensure it works flawlessly on every install, and regardless of what other packages are installed. This is only possible when they can look at the package repository, and know every other package which could potentially be installed. (In practice, they may only be concerned with a small subset of the packages; such as the libc toolchain, and the SDL libraries, for example.)

Compiling packages yourself is (by comparison) fast and loose: you don't care about maximizing portability; you just want it to build and work on your machine. You don't care if there are incompatibilities with stuff under `/usr`, since it will not get overwritten, and you are free to install an incompatible duplicate of any library, so long as you stay under `/usr/local`. You may even have very specific requirements (e.g. taking advantage of your machine's specific instruction set for boosted performance) which do not apply to other users of your linux distribution. And, if it is incompatible with some other piece of software you haven't installed yet, you'll deal with that when trying to install the new software, not in advance.

Comment: Side note: When you're installing a whole stack of packages for a specific purpose, or installing anything from a 3rd party vendor, it's common practice to isolate these from the possible mess under `/usr/local`, while also protecting the stability of `/usr`, by installing each to a unique place under `/opt/<vendor-name>` or `/opt/<stack-name>`.